# How can i set an arduino pin act like a jumper?

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project that has an ethernet module. I want to use a pin of Arduino Mega act like a jumper. If jumper is open (jumper cap removed) IP address will be assigned static otherwise it will be optained from a DHCP server. I use Digital pin 53 and set pinMode to INPUT_PULLUP. The other side of the jumper is connected to GND. Is it true what i am doing or will it fry something (if jumper cap is attached permanently)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be safe as long as the pin is never set to output and high. AVR pins default to input, just ensure you use the pullup resistor otherwise the pin will be floating when not connected to ground.

Using the internal pullup is common with buttons. Your jumper is replacing the button in the below diagram.

When its not connected, the input pin will read high, and low when connected.

[image: MCU pullup]

Picture from here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pull-up-resistors (link is worth a read).